# Stubbing RestTeamplate with ArgumentMatchers is not resolving

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have a piece of code which cals an external api , i would like to write test cases to cover the same.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(REQ_ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        headers.set(UUID, pojo.getUuid());
        headers.set(CHANNEL_ID, APIN_CHANNEL_ID);
        headers.set(BUSINESS_CODE, APIN_BUSINESS_CODE);
        headers.set(COUNTRYCODE, CountryCode.valueOf(pojo.getCountry().toUpperCase()).getCode());
        headers.set(MESSAGE_ID, APIN_MESSAGE_ID);
        headers.set(VERSION_NO, APIN_VERSION_NO);
        headers.set(CLIENT_SECRET, clientSecret);
        headers.set(CLIENT_ID, clientId);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(solaceResponse, headers);
        logger.info("getInternalApimRespose uri-{}", url);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);

        externalResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
```

and the junit for the above is ..

```
String string = "result";
    Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>>any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()))
            .thenReturn(generateResponseEntityObject(string, HttpStatus.OK));

private ResponseEntity<String> generateResponseEntityObject(String response, HttpStatus httpStatus){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
}
```

i have tried all different combinations of argument matchers and mockito.any statement, none of them seems to work..

iam getting exception below..

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'postForEntity' method:
    mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(
    null,
    <{"requestBody":{"reqDateTime":null,"reqCardNumber":"5467182634567658","reqPinEncryptionType":null,"reqEncryptedPin":null}},[reqAccept:"application/json", uuid:"null", channelId:"GRC", businessCode:"ICG", countryCode:"EU", messageId:"0401", versionNo:"01", clientSecret:"null", clientId:"null", Content-Type:"application/json"]>,
    class java.lang.String
);
    -> at com.citi.tts.grace.apin.connector.service.ApinConnectorClient.getInternalApimResponse(ApinConnectorClient.java:96)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(
    "",
    null,
    null
);
      -> at com.citi.tts.grace.apin.conector.service.ApinConnetorClientTest.testGetInternalApimResponse(ApinConnetorClientTest.java:68)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
    at com.citi.tts.grace.apin.connector.service.ApinConnectorClient.getInternalApimResponse(ApinConnectorClient.java:96)
    at com.citi.tts.grace.apin.conector.service.ApinConnetorClientTest.testGetInternalApimResponse(ApinConnetorClientTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at
```

i have referred these pages..

1. [Mockito mocking restTemplate.postForEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272391/mockito-mocking-resttemplate-postforentity)
2. [How to Mock Rest template using mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526247/how-to-mock-rest-template-using-mockito)

> EDIT: i have also tried to use lenient mocking to avoid this , but the
> return type of that stubbed method always returns null

```
Mockito.lenient().when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.eq(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(generateResponseEntityObject(result, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: this comment does not help at all.@gavin

Comment: @Eran can you help